# Shift of the position of extrema

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have noticed the following thing and I would like to know if it holds in general.

Having a (positive) function $f(x)$ with extrema (maximum/minimum) and a function $g(x)$ which is strictly decreasing, then the extrema of the product of these functions are shifted to the left in comparison to the original extrema.

Example:

Let $f(x)=e^{-(x-2)^2}$ has a simple maximum at $x_0=2$. Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly decreasing.
Taking the product $f(x)g(x)=\frac{e^{-(x-2)^2}}{x}$ we see that the ''original'' maximum shifts to the left to $x_0=1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

First of all, I am wondering if this holds true for any such functions. Intuitively it makes sense - the decreasing function pushes everything to the left. But how can I prove it? Maybe it is some known theorem?

Second, are there some bounds on this "displacement" of the extrema, given the original position and the derivative of the decreasing function? (in my example the difference between original position and shifted position was $1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$).

Of course, any counterexamples are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like something that is generally true. For instance, what  would be the "shift" when $f(x)g(x)$ has more extrema than $f(x)$.

We have that the extrema of $f(x)g(x) $ are found by solving$$f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=0,$$ where we know that $g'(x)<0$. We can't really get anything general out of this, since we still allow $f'(x)$ and $g(x)$ to behave quite erratically.

Take for instance $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=-x$ and $h(x)=\frac1x$.  The resulting functions $f(x)g(x)$ and $f(x)h(x)$ don't have the same number of extrema, so what now?

So I would say that you did not stumble upon some general truth, eventhough I could not find functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where the extrema are actually shifted to the right.

Comment: I also think that there must be some additional constraint on the functions, e.g., $f(x)$ is bounded (see my example), but it seems to me that you could always "map" the original extrema to the new extrema. In your example, $x^2$ has extrema $-\infty$, $0$, $\infty$, which is the same as $f(x)g(x)$ (there has been no shift in the positions), while in $f(x)h(x)$ the $0$ minimum could be thought as it has been shifted to $-\infty$, while $+\infty$ remained the same.